# Special character in database.yml for password

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have my database password starting with a '*'. When i put this on my production server i get following error:

```
- syntax error on line 17, col 25: ` password: *---------'.Exception class:ArgumentError.
```

Thanks,
Anubhaw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The asterisk (`*`) has special meaning in YAML. Try using a quoted scalar:

```
password: '*-------'
```